# Spark sql- Do an aggregation based on another aggregation option

Tags: sql, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, dataset

I have this data frame below, what I'm trying to achieve is, *only* when a row has a 'Y' flag, the values in the `code` column would be aggregated into a list. I have tried the sql blow but that did not work. How to do this? I commented in the code and sample output below. Many thanks for your help.

Input :

```
name            code    flag
big bird          A       Y
elmo              B       N     
cookie monster    C       Y
cookie monster    D       N
```

Expected output:

```
name              hasYflag    Codelist
big bird            Y          A.   
elmo                N               //elmo does not have codelist as the flag is N
cookie monster      Y          C,D. //cookie monster has codelist as there is one Y (row 3 above) flag
```

I have tried to do it this way but it does not work. I hope to do this with spark sql but not Spark sql api:

```
select name,
case when max(flag) = "Y" then "Y" else "N" end as hasYflag
case when max(flag) = "Y" then sort_array(collect_set(code)) else null as Codelist
from df
groupby name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```scala
    import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

    data
      .withColumn("code", collect_set("code") over Window.partitionBy("name"))
      .withColumn("rank", row_number() over Window.partitionBy("name").orderBy(col("flag").desc))
      .where(col("rank") === 1)
      .withColumn("code", when(col("flag") === lit("Y"), concat_ws(",", col("code"))))
      .withColumnRenamed("flag", "hasYFlag")
      .withColumnRenamed("code", "codeList")
      .select("name", "codeList", "hasYFlag")
```

Output:

```
+--------------+--------+--------+
|          name|codeList|hasYFlag|
+--------------+--------+--------+
|cookie monster|     C,D|       Y|
|      big bird|       A|       Y|
|          elmo|    null|       N|
+--------------+--------+--------+
```

As requested (edit):

```scala
sparkSession.sql("WITH dups AS (
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY flag DESC) AS rn 
FROM (
SELECT name, flag, CONCAT_WS(',', COLLECT_SET(code) OVER (PARTITION BY name)) AS code FROM tmp_table)
) SELECT name, flag AS hasYFlag, IF(flag='Y', code, null) AS codeList FROM dups WHERE rn = 1")
```

Comment: Thanks but is there a way without using APIs, but do it with sql?

Comment: by sql I mean in this way `spark.sql("....")` many thanks

Comment: @user4046073 See updated answer. Please rate it as the right answer if it perfectly answers your question :-)